# Edge ignores script-src in Content Security Policy

Tags: microsoft-edge, content-security-policy

I have the following Content Security Policy

```
value="default-src 'self'
       style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; 
       script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://svc.webspellchecker.net; 
       img-src 'self' data: https://s3.amazonaws.com;
       frame-src 'self' *.salesforce.com *.force.com;"
```

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox. In Edge it is not running because we have some inline scripts (ie `onClick="foo()`).

My understanding is the the `default-src` sets the defaults and the `script-src` should override those defaults.

Does anyone know if this is a bug in Edge, or if I've botched it in some way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that though that is the way our CSP looks in our web.test.config, the transform puts the following into the web.config

```
value="default-src 'self'&#xD;&#xA;           style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; &#xD;&#xA;
       script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://svc.webspellchecker.net; &#xD;&#xA;           img-src 'self' data: https://s3.amazonaws.com;&#xD;&#xA;           frame-src 'self' *.salesforce.com *.force.com;"
```

Basically the XDT replaces the CRLFs in the value with 
, which causes Edge to give up on processing the CSP so you only get the first line.

Bug submitted.
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/2272282/edge-stops-processing-content-security-policy-on-xd-xa

Comment: can you provide a link to the bug you submitted?

Comment: Had to ctrl+shift+t about 30 times, but I added the link :)

Comment: thanks a ton, I'll make sure this gets higher visibility internally. would you be able to add a comment either here or on the bug that includes a demo url?

Comment: I tried publishing a simple repro to Azure, but Azure apparently masks the problem (we're hosting IIS in a VM, I'm also able to repro locally). I put together a simple project and tried to upload that to the bug but I don't see that attached to the bug anywhere.

Also, noticed that Edge seems to cache the CSP. If I view a page with a broken CSP, then fix the CSP, the page remains broken until I open F12 tools and refresh. I added that info to the bug, not sure if I should submit a second bug for that.

Comment: making a seperate bug makes it a lot more useful. posting a zip of a file that can be hosted on IIS works too! and thank you for all of the work you have done