# Error - This Internet Explorer instance does not have the following capabilities: privateNetworkClientServer

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, salesforce, microsoft-edge

I have a Canvas application in salesforce.com
The basic thing that a canvas application does is that it opens an external webpage in an IFRAME. The issue I have started facing for the past two days affects **Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge**.

This is working without any issues in Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox, but a large number of my users are using IE. The page being served is over the https protocol. It does not have any mixed content. **How can I make it work in IE & Edge?**

When I click on the link, it throws the following error message:

```
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
CSP14309: Unknown directive 'referrer' in Content-Security-Policy - directive will be ignored.
CSP14303: Content-Security-Policy policy was empty.
HTML1524: Invalid HTML5 DOCTYPE. Consider using the interoperable form "<!DOCTYPE html>".
CSP14309: Unknown directive 'referrer' in Content-Security-Policy - directive will be ignored.
CSP14309: Unknown directive 'upgrade-insecure-requests' in Content-Security-Policy - directive will be ignored.
CSP14303: Content-Security-Policy policy was empty.
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
GET - https://login.salesforce.com/17181/logo180.png
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
GET - https://login.salesforce.com/17181/logo180.png
CSP14309: Unknown directive 'referrer' in Content-Security-Policy - directive will be ignored.
CSP14303: Content-Security-Policy policy was empty.
SEC7117: Network request to https://MYWEBPAGE-REDACTED/CanvasLanding.aspx did not succeed.
This Internet Explorer instance does not have the following capabilities: privateNetworkClientServer 
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by ms-appx-web://microsoft.microsoftedge/assets/errorpages/dnserror.html
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by ms-appx-web://microsoft.microsoftedge/assets/errorpages/ErrorPageStyles.css
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by ms-appx-web://microsoft.microsoftedge/Assets/ErrorPages/ErrorPageScripts.js
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by ms-appx-web:///assets/Fonts/BrowserMDL.ttf#Browser MDL2 Assets
dnserror.html
CSP14309: Unknown directive 'referrer' in Content-Security-Policy - directive will be ignored.
CSP14303: Content-Security-Policy policy was empty.
```

Comment: Hi, has this happened to all of your customers using your salesforce app? Are they using their own custom company login page? https://domain.my.salesforce.com? Does this happen if they use InPrivate browsing in IE and Edge?

Comment: Yes. This has happened to all of my users who are using salesforce. The InPrivate browsing mode is disabled for them by our company's admins.

Comment: It would appear that changes on the salesforce site may be a cause... eg. copy and paste https://login.salesforce.com/17181/logo180.png into any browser address bar and you get the 404 error. You can find an outdated explanation of IE/Edge CSP error codes at https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/MicrosoftEdge-Documentation/commit/c2b7fafb39785606a06cf80fe0d5443a2874835f

Comment: ....correction...see this stackoverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34954042/edge-ignores-script-scr-in-content-security-policy

Comment: any solutions found?